# AWS S3 methods mapping to Guzzle Request class

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, guzzle

I've encountered a rather confusing issue with the new PHP SDK for AWS. I installed the AWS SDK for PHP with Composer and I'm using the latest stable release. Unfortunately, it appears as though the S3 methods are mapping directly to the Guzzle\Http\Message\Request class and I have absolutely no idea why! Can anyone help?

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Aws\Common\Aws;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

$aws = S3Client::factory(
    array(
        "key"       => "exampleKeyMeep381717",
        "secret"    => "exampleSecretMeep291581",
        "region"    => "us-east-1"
    )
);

$s3 = $aws->get("s3");

$result = $s3->createBucket(array("Bucket" => "bmucket92hta"));
```

And this is the error that is being printed to the screen:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Guzzle\Http\Message\Request::createBucket()
```

Answer (score 2):

I see what is happening. You have

```
$aws = S3Client::factory(
```

Which creates an instance of the S3 client. Then you have

```
$s3 = $aws->get("s3");
```

Which (since the SDK clients inherit from the Guzzle HTTP client) creates a Request object.

---

What I think you meant to do is

```
$aws = Aws::factory(
```

Which creates an instance of the AWS service builder. And then do

```
$s3 = $aws->get("s3");
```

Like you are doing now, except with the correct object, to get the S3 client instance.

Is this a code sample you got from somewhere in particular?

Comment: Thanks a million! I appreciate it. I missed this when working with the documentation.